# find webpage name when not displaying on url

Tags: url

Here is a URL that shows the directory but no webpage name.
http://houstonballet.org/Academy/Summer-Audition-Tour/

How do I go about getting the exact webpage name?  I tried plugging in index.html, index.asp, etc.

Comment: Chrome developer tools says http://houstonballet.org/Academy/Summer-Audition-Tour/Default.htm (Network -> Response Headers -> Content Location)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can trace the http request/response via browser(chrome) devtools network tab

Full response header

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 88706
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Location: http://houstonballet.org/Academy/Summer-Audition-Tour/Default.htm
Last-Modified: Tue, 24 Nov 2015 17:14:36 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
ETag: "33476998db26d11:2011"
Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
```

http://houstonballet.org/Academy/Summer-Audition-Tour/Default.htm is your landing page